# Django Detail View returns 404 error (other stackoverflow solutions don't work)

Tags: django, django-views

I recently asked a question about DetialViews and linkify, but realized, the problem was not with the linkify, but getting the Detail View to show up. Whenever I try to get the detail view to show up, I get "404 error". How to get this to work? I've literally been working on this for a week, please help. I don't know where to look.

Here is urls.py url patterns: (I've tried a bunch of different patterns and cannot get it to work.)

```
path('hospitals/', views.HospitalListView.as_view(), name='hospital_list'),
re_path(r'^hospitals/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.HospitalDetailView.as_view(), name='hospital_detail')
```

Here is my views.py:

```
class HospitalListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Hospital
    context_object_name = 'hospital_list'
    template_name = 'hospital_list.html'

class HospitalDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Hospital
    def hospital_detail_view(request, primary_key):
        hospital = get_object_or_404(Hospital, pk='primary_key')
        return render(request, 'hospital_detail.html', {'hospital': hospital})
```

Here is my models.py.

```
class Hospital(models.Model):
    """Model representing Hospitals."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    hopid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular hospital in database')
    location_text = models.CharField(max_length = 800)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['hopid']

    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return f'{self.name} ({self.location_text})'
```

Here is my html file - hospital_list.html

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Hospital List</h1>
  {% if hospital_list %}
  <ul>
    {% for hospital in hospital_list %}
      <li>
        <a href="{% url 'hospital_detail' pk=hospital.pk %}">{{ hospital.name }}</a> ({{hospital.location_text}})
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  {% else %}
    <p>There are no hospitals listed in your area.</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Here is hospital_detail.html

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1> Hospital Name: {{ hospital.name }}</h1>
    <p><strong> Location: </strong>{{ hospital.location_text }}</p>
    <p><strong> Phone Number:</strong> {{ hospital.phone }}</p>
    <p><strong> Reviews: {{ hospital.reviews }</p>
{% endblock %}
```

SOLVED: Thanks for everyone's help. I don't know what was wrong. I did a few things and it solved it.

1. I changed my primary key to hospital name rather than uuid. I just called it as primary key.
2. I deleted my databases and reran migrations.

This fixed it. Any help on understanding why would be great?

Comment: If you manually type URLs then does it working?

Comment: I just tried putting in hospital/uuid/ manually and it does not work. How would you put it in manually?

Comment: checkout https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview

Comment: @JR are you using uuid in url : like  /hospital/23-304kd03-4-30ddo-3/

Comment: do you want  details of hopid field from model

Comment: Yes, I am using the uuid in the url. I tried to change my primary key to the non-uuid name field to try to change this, but was unable. I think the error might be due to that. How might I fix this?

Comment: I don't need the hopid field, could also use the name field.

Comment: I'm little confused, please tell that you want to use uuid as your primary key or pk as primary key, and what you want pass in your urls

Comment: Both name and uuid are unique, I can pass either. I thought that maybe the uuid is causing me problems.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is because you are assigning pk a string

```
class HospitalListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Hospital
    context_object_name = 'hospital_list'
    template_name = 'hospital_list.html'

class HospitalDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Hospital
    def hospital_detail_view(request, pk): # change here
        hospital = get_object_or_404(Hospital, pk=pk)  #oldone->pk='primary_key')
        return render(request, 'hospital_detail.html', {'hospital': hospital})
```

also in urls try:

```
path('hospitals/<int:pk>', views.HospitalDetailView.as_view(), name='hospital_detail')
```

even if this didnot work then make sure you are receiving pk value in the view, I think its the only reason for that. try to print the pk value in url to know that you are receiving it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've tried this. It does print the string. Here's the error I get. Maybe it helps:The current path, hospitals/(?P977db815-8248-4871-9305-865490174495[\w\d-]+)/, didn't match any of these. Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/hospitals/(%3FP977db815-8248-4871-9305-865490174495%5B%5Cw%5Cd-%5D+)/

Answer (score 0):

generic views are built for "Do Not Repeat Yourself" try below code.

## url

```
path('hospitals/<int:pk>/', views.HospitalDetailView.as_view(), name='hospital_detail')
```

## view

```
class HospitalDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Hospital
    template_name = "hospital_detail.html"
```

## In browser url exmaple i.e pk=2

```
http://localhost:8000/hospitals/2/
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I really appreciate it. I tried it, but it still does not work. I'm still getitng the "404 error". Using the URLconf defined in django1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns:

admin/
[name='index']
lookup/ [name='lookup']
results/ [name='results']
hospitals/ [name='hospital_list']
^hospitals/<int:pk>/ [name='hospital_detail']
post/ [name='post_new']
contact/ [name='contact']
about/ [name='about']
mapview/ [name='mapview']
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, hospitals/(?P977db815-8248-4871-9305-865490174495[\w\d-]+)/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: you should pass `pk` as `integer` not `uuid`. checkout updated code.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but when I put in your code and enter this in the browser - I get the same error:The current path, hospitals/2/, didn't match any of these. Am I missing something? I'm new to Django, so I definitely might be.

Comment: @ Anjaneyulu, I shared the traceback with you in my first comment. It's just the 404 error page with the following: Using the URLconf defined in django1.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
lookup/ [name='lookup']
results/ [name='results']
hospitals/ [name='hospital_list']
^hospitals/<int:pk>/ [name='hospital_detail']
post/ [name='post_new']
contact/ [name='contact']
about/ [name='about']
mapview/ [name='mapview']
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, hospitals/2/, didn't match any of these. (This is the 404 traceback for your code).

Comment: there was a mistake in url path. I updated it check it out now.

Answer (score 0):

In the views.py,

```
class HospitalDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Hospital
    template_name = 'hospital_detail.html'
```

In the template

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Hospital List</h1>
  <ul>
     {% for hospital in hospital_list %}
     <li>
         <a href="{% url 'hospital_detail' hospital.pk %}">{{ hospital.name }}</a> 
         ({{hospital.location_text}})
     </li>
  </ul>
     {% empty %}
          <p>There are no hospitals listed in your area.</p>
     {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

In the urls.py,

```
path('hospitals/<int:pk>/', views.HospitalDetailView.as_view(), name='hospital_detail')
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. Still getting the 404 error. Could there be something wrong in settings?

Comment: @JR I don't think, there is anything wrong in this code. Can you share your error traceback.